# My LAMP Custom Server won't display PHP code

Tags: php, lamp, webserver, html5, web-development

I have a 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I made myself a LAMP custom server by mostly following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrLAx27Npns). I already had PHP and apache2, and I didn't install the workflow-speeding custom commands, but otherwise I followed the instructions. I made *index.php* file as the video suggested, and added some text, even tough it wasn't instructed:

```
<?php

echo "This is a PHP text";
?>
```

It worked as intended.

However, when I replaced with with *index.html*:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>A Title</title>
    </head>
    
    <style>
    body
    {
        background-color: pink;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    
    <p>This is an HTML text</p>
    
    <button type="button"
    onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
    Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    
    <img src="Image.png">

    <?php
    echo "This is a PHP text";
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

HTML, CSS, and JavaScript work fine the Php-part won't show, despite *index.php* working. Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* you want `.pgn`? Images that start with the letter “P” are usually `.png` 

Comment: Yeah solved the image thing. Pgn asde the server apparently doesn't accept special markings like "ä", which was in my actual image name.

Comment: Is it OK, that you PHP code (and image) is located after `</body>` and `</html>` tags? I am not sure how browsers treat that. It is possible, that anything after `</body>`  or `</html>` tag is ignored.

Comment: Sorry, I had edited the HTML in example in order to display issues better, but I accidentally put them behind those tags. I assure that in the original code body and html tags were last, and it still didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood, but you said that the codes does not work in index.html file!
it is because the **extension** of file! rename the file from **index.html** to **index.php** or something else with .php suffix.

when you save a file as .html, the system treats it like as a HTML file. so if you want to run PHP codes, you must save it as **.php** file.

Comment: You read right. But how come in w3schools.com can HTML contain php code?

Comment: Yes, but the opposite is true! I mean, in fact PHP code can contain HTML,  not PHP in HTML. because when you use PHP for create a webpage in server, you need to show the result to user, so you must use HTML in that PHP codes. but in opposite condition, when you create a HTML page for user, there is no server side codes like PHP.
So, if you have PHP codes in a PHP file, you can show the results as HTML pages.this is about headers! for example you can print the results of PHP file as a JSON file not HTML, or even a PDF file! read about content type header in PHP.